# Issue with storing unique IP address from the visitor of my website

Tags: php, networking, ip

**Before marking my question as duplicate please go through this description.**

Here is the function that I'm using to get the IP address of the visitor

```
function get_client_ip() {
    $ipaddress = '';
    if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
       $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
    else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
    else
        $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
    return $ipaddress;
}
```

I'm aware that with this function I will get the same IP address of two devices under same network. However, my problem is that every day this function fetches new IP address for the same device under the same address. For eg. When I used my laptop on Monday the IP address it showed was `117.196.22.134`, every time I checked this was the same IP that was been displayed. Next day i.e. Tuesday when I checked using the same laptop a different IP was displayed. So any suggestions how to get a unique IP from the visitor everyday? It will also be very helpful if you can inform me how to differentiate each device within the same network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your router may be configured with DHCP that why you are getting different ip every new day.

Solution : ask you provider to provide static IP on your internet connection. and configure that IP into your laptop adapter settings.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's not only about me. I have a website www.ImgEcho.com in which different users would be visiting and while testing I observed that the IP address of my users also chages everyday. I can't tell my users to contact their ISP.